# How to query when joining 3 queries into 1 table?

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports

I have 3 queries:

```
// (1)
String sql = "SELECT tblClientInfo.ClientID, tblrefmarket.MarketDesc, tblclientinfo.LastName, tblledger.LoanAmount, "
+ "tblledger.DateStarted, tblledger.DailyPay, tblledger.Expiry FROM tblclientinfo Inner Join tblbusinessinfo ON tblbusinessinfo.ClientID = tblclientinfo.ClientID "
+ "Inner Join tblrefmarket ON tblbusinessinfo.MarketID = tblrefmarket.MarketID "
+ "Inner Join tblledger ON tblledger.ClientID = tblclientinfo.ClientID where MarketDesc = ?";

// (2)
String sumSQL = "SELECT ClientID, sum(tblloanpayment.AmountPaid) as sum FROM tblloanpayment where tblloanpayment.ClientID= ? ";

// (3)
String balSQL = "SELECT (SELECT tblLedger.LoanAmount from tblLedger WHERE tblLedger.ClientID = ?) - (SELECT SUM(tblLoanPayment.AmountPaid) "
+ "FROM tblLoanPayment WHERE tblLoanPayment.ClientID = ?) as balance FROM dual; ";
```

I have executed this 3 queries to display informations on a jTable. And it was successful.

Now my problem is when I am generating the report (or print) using JasperReports.

I can only display the 1st query since it is inside the database. While query 2 and 3 are not. They are just computations of the payments made in query 1.

How can I join this so that I can be able to display all necessary informations?

Here's my code:

```
private void cmdPrintActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int row = tableMarket.getSelectedRow();
    try {
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("notes receivables.jrxml");
        String sql = "SELECT tblClientInfo.ClientID, tblrefmarket.MarketDesc, tblclientinfo.LastName, tblledger.LoanAmount, "
                + "tblledger.DateStarted, tblledger.DailyPay, tblledger.Expiry FROM tblclientinfo Inner Join tblbusinessinfo ON tblbusinessinfo.ClientID = tblclientinfo.ClientID "
                + "Inner Join tblrefmarket ON tblbusinessinfo.MarketID = tblrefmarket.MarketID "
                + "Inner Join tblledger ON tblledger.ClientID = tblclientinfo.ClientID where MarketDesc = '" + tableMarket.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString() + "'";
        JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
        newQuery.setText(sql);
        jasperDesign.setQuery(newQuery);
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, conn);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

This code displays only the first query.

Comment: You have different structure of data in your queries. How you can union this data? Your question is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already selecting `tblLedger.LoanAmount` in your first query, so the only additional information required from both your second and third queries is `sum(tblloanpayment.AmountPaid)`. Try:

```
SELECT c.ClientID, 
       m.MarketDesc, 
       c.LastName, 
       l.LoanAmount, 
       l.DateStarted, 
       l.DailyPay, 
       l.Expiry,
       s.sumPaid,
       l.LoanAmount - s.sumPaid as balance
FROM tblclientinfo c
Inner Join tblbusinessinfo b ON b.ClientID = c.ClientID 
Inner Join tblrefmarket m ON b.MarketID = m.MarketID
Inner Join tblledger l ON l.ClientID = c.ClientID 
left join (SELECT ClientID, sum(AmountPaid) as sumPaid 
           FROM tblloanpayment group by ClientID) s on c.ClientID = s.ClientID 
where m.MarketDesc = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the restriction by client id in the second and third queries.  Make them into subselects (that is, put them in parentheses) and make a big select that joins all three subselects on client id.

**Edit**

So if the three queries are query1, query2, query3, you'd end up with

```
select ... from (query1) baseSql 
join (query2) sumSql on baseSql.clientId = sumSql.clientId  
join (query3) balSql on baseSql.clientId = balSql.clientId
```

You may need to use `left join` instead of `join` if there are rows in `baseSql` that are missing from `sumSql` or `balSql`.

Comment: The alias that I used for the first subselect.